# Ignore package build when updating conda environment on Windows

Tags: anaconda, conda

I want to update my Windows conda environmment from `.yml` file exported from Linux. Unluckily for me, `.yml` file also contains the build of the package i.e.

```
- numpy=1.17.2=py37haad9e8e_0
```

which, when running on Windows yields
`ResolvePackageNotFound` error, just because the build is present. Is there a way to ignore the build while *updating* the environment i.e. something like `conda env update --file exp_env.yml --no-build --prune`?

Comment: I am not aware of such an option, but it might be a good idea to simply export the env using the `--from-history` flag, which will omit the build tags in the output, see [here](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#exporting-an-environment-file-across-platforms)

Comment: @FlyingTeller I have no access to the desired environment and hence I cannot re-export it. `exp_env.yml` is all I have